# MAMP with Laravel Unix Socket

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm working with MAMP on my local development server on my laravel application and I'm trying to figure out how I can safely setup my server so I don't have to use the following into the database connections mysql array because that should only be used when I'm on my development server. It works when I add the line into the mysql array however that isn't used if I was on a production server. Any ideas?

```
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

.env.development.php

```
<?php

return [
    'DB_HOST' => '127.0.0.1',
    'DB_USERNAME' => 'root',
    'DB_PASSWORD' => '1234',
    'DB_NAME' => 'mytable'
];
```

app/config/database.php

```
'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
            'username'  => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the *environment detection* part in the `bootstrap/start.php`. You should add your machine's name to the array that has `local` key. (If you don't know your machine's name, run `hostname` in terminal. If it's something stupid, Google how to change it. It's pretty simple.) Then copy and paste your database configurations to `app/config/local/database.php`. Create the file if it doesn't exists.

Comment: Good answer but nothing to do with the question. I was asking unix socket specific.

Comment: @user3732216 Your question stated you need to use the `unix_socket` value on your dev machine alone. So just include that line for the config in your `app/config/local/database.php`, and not include in your production `app/config/database.php`.

Comment: But if you notice I'm using environment variables and what not.

Comment: I understood that. Proceed with what I said. If you use `development` as your environment name, then create the file `app/config/development/database.php` and copy the exact contents of `app/config/database.php` into this file and just add the line about that socket thing.

Answer (score 16):

There is even simple solution. add this to ur .env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 6):

On `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'unix_socket' => env('UNIX_SOCKET'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

On `.env`:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mytable
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure MAMP preference is set to Apache port: 80, Nginx Port: 80, MySQL Port: 3306

Here's what worked for me with Laravel 5.7:

go to config/database.php and find the line 54 below:

before:
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),

After:
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),

Save the file.

Then in terminal run:
php artisan config:cache
php artisan migrate

Comment: Your `php artisan config:cache` saved me. I've been banging my head with this error for days. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions worked for you,

Try actually starting your webserver as this was the fix for me